# Tramp not reusing connections for Git commands

Tags: magit, tramp, vc

I am debugging a very slow performance of git commands over SSH, including via packages such as VC and Magit.

Even using VC on `emacs -Q` is extremely slow.

I get

```
Tramp: Opening connection git for <<hostname>> using ssh
```

over and over, when I would expect TRAMP to reuse the first connection.

What is strange is that this behavior seems to be confined to `git` commands: if I open eshell and run `ls`, TRAMP opens a new connection only once (and the following commands runs quite fast). In this case, the output is (attention to `nil` instead of `git`):

```
Tramp: Opening connection nil for <<hostname>> using ssh
```

Conversely, if I do `git status`, every time the command is run, a new connection is opened, with the text mentioned above.

Would someone know how to make TRAMP reuse the connection even for `git` commands?

Comment: eshell implements its own `ls` command in elisp, so I think that's not a good comparison.  `which ls` => "`eshell/ls` is a byte-compiled Lisp function in ‘em-ls.el’."

Comment: Maybe research/check your ControlMaster config for ssh.  That's the "normal" approach I'm familiar with for getting ssh to re-use its connections.  For a while now Tramp has tried to make use of that by default, but it may depend on which Tramp method you're using, and/or how ssh is configured on your system.

Answer (score 0):

In vc, `vc-git-command` is called, which uses `vc-do-command`. This uses an asynchronous process via `start-file-process`, and so does Tramp: opening a new process for a given git command.

I haven't checked for magit, but something similar might happen.

You might try to improve the performance by using direct async processes in Tramp (see its manual).